# Securing Carrierwave Upload error - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, carrierwave

I've been trying to add uploads to my rails project following this article: [How To: Secure Upload](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-To:-Secure-Upload).  Everything seems to work fine, but I am getting a no method error on the index view:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007f690e634600>:0x007f690e620718>):
24:          
25:          <tr>
26:             <td><%= resume.name %></td>
27:             <td><%= link_to File.basename(f.resume.url), "/uploads/#{f.id}/#{File.basename(f.resume.url)}" %></td>
28:             <td><%= button_to "Delete",  resume, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{resume.name}?" %></td>
29:          </tr>
30:
```

app/views/resumes/index.html.erb:27:in `block in _app_views_resumes_index_html_erb___1440061793164452865_70044592937660'
  app/views/resumes/index.html.erb:23:in`_app_views_resumes_index_html_erb___1440061793164452865_70044592937660'

My model:

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.
   validates :name, presence: true # Make sure the owner's name is present.
end
```

My Controller:

```
    class ResumesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @resumes = Resume.all
   end

   def new
      @resume = Resume.new
   end

   def create
      @resume = Resume.new(resume_params)

      if @resume.save
         redirect_to resumes_path, notice: "The resume #{@resume.name} has been uploaded."
      else
         render "new"
      end

   end
   def download
     path = "/#{resume.resume}"
   send_file path, :x_sendfile=>true
   end
   def destroy
      @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
      @resume.destroy
      redirect_to resumes_path, notice:  "The resume #{@resume.name} has been deleted."
   end

   private
      def resume_params
      params.require(:resume).permit(:name, :attachment)
   end

end
```

My Index View:

```
    <% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
   <div class = "alert alert-info">
      <%= flash[:notice] %>
   </div>
<% end %>

<br />

<%= link_to "New Resume", new_resume_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<br />
<br />

<table class = "table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>.
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Download Link</th>
         <th> </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
      <% @resumes.each do |resume| %>

         <tr>
            <td><%= resume.name %></td>
            <td><%= link_to File.basename(f.resume.url), "/uploads/#{f.id}/#{File.basename(f.resume.url)}" %></td>
            <td><%= button_to "Delete",  resume, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{resume.name}?" %></td>
         </tr>

      <% end %>
   </tbody>

</table>
```

I've been googling answers for hours and can't seem to track down a solution based on previous answers.  Apologies if one was overlooked.

Comment: You're using `f.resume.url` in your view, what is `f`?  You haven't defined it anywhere.
Maybe you meant: `resume.url` instead

Answer (score 0):

there is a typo in the how-to (and this how-to aslo http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-file-uploading.htm) . just rename @resumes -> @resume in the view and the controller.